# .wav to .flac converter in C#

Tags: c#, audio

My program is recording voice in .wav and convert it to .flac 
I will send this .flac file to google, hope I will get the text of the voice.
But there's error when my program trying to send the file to google, "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\Ahmad Mustofa\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\FP\voice.flac' because it is being used by another process." . I don't know which process that still use that file.
Here is my code :

```
        string inputFile = Path.Combine("wav ", input);//the converter
        string outputFile = Path.Combine("flac", Path.ChangeExtension(input, ".flac"));

        if (!File.Exists(inputFile))
            throw new ApplicationException("Input file " + inputFile + " cannot be found!");

        WavReader wav = new WavReader(inputFile);
        FlacWriter flac = new FlacWriter(File.Create(outputFile), wav.BitDepth, wav.Channels, wav.SampleRate);
        // Buffer for 1 second's worth of audio data
        byte[] buffer = new byte[wav.Bitrate / 8];
        int bytesRead;
        do
        {
            bytesRead = wav.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            flac.Convert(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        } while (bytesRead > 0);
        flac.Dispose();
        flac = null;
        wav.Dispose();
        wav = null;
        //the sender
            FileStream FS_Audiofile = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Ahmad Mustofa\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\FP\\voice.flac", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader BR_Audiofile = new BinaryReader(FS_Audiofile);
            byte[] BA_AudioFile = BR_Audiofile.ReadBytes((Int32)FS_Audiofile.Length);
            FS_Audiofile.Close();
            BR_Audiofile.Close();

            HttpWebRequest _HWR_SpeechToText = null;

            _HWR_SpeechToText = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&lang=de-DE&maxresults=1&pfilter=0");

            _HWR_SpeechToText.Method = "POST";
            _HWR_SpeechToText.ContentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=44100";
            _HWR_SpeechToText.ContentLength = BA_AudioFile.Length;
            _HWR_SpeechToText.GetRequestStream().Write(BA_AudioFile, 0, BA_AudioFile.Length);

            HttpWebResponse HWR_Response = (HttpWebResponse)_HWR_SpeechToText.GetResponse();
            if (HWR_Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                StreamReader SR_Response = new StreamReader(HWR_Response.GetResponseStream());
            }
```

Comment: You say you don't know what process is using the file, so that seems to be the first thing to find out! What do you see if you search for the file in Process Hacker or Process Explorer?

Comment: The file is used by the converter. I have tried to dispose the flacwriter, but it changes nothing.
so please give me some solution about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure, that `FlacWriter` disposes the `Stream` automatically? You could try something like this:

```
...

using (var flacStream = File.Create(outputFile))
{
    FlacWriter flac = new FlacWriter(flacStream, wav.BitDepth, wav.Channels, wav.SampleRate);
    // Buffer for 1 second's worth of audio data
    byte[] buffer = new byte[wav.Bitrate / 8];
    int bytesRead;
    do
    {
        bytesRead = wav.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        flac.Convert(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    } while (bytesRead > 0);
    flac.Dispose();
    flac = null;
}

...
```